# open HTML file from desktop directly into Sublime?

Tags: html, sublimetext3

I have saved an HTML file from sublime to my desktop, which saves as a web link, fair enough, understandable...

But what I'd like to know is is there a way to open that file from my desktop directly into sublime, instead of into the browser

I can right click and open with - sublime text, annoying

I've saved just as plain text, but then when I open in sublime, it no longer gives the option to open in browser.

I assumed this would be a common question but can't seem to find it anywhere, sorry if it's been asked and answered before!

Comment: just to confirm, i have tried altering the default program to open with, through right click and properties... i have actual webpages saved to my desktop, and when i do this, it defaults all web pages to open through sublime..??

Answer (score 1):

The main way would be to set in your OS `.html` to be opened in Sublime rather than with Browser. (This changes default behavior though so if you ever want it to be opened in Browser then you have to decide which one you want as default and which one you are okay with Right clicking and Opening with)

On Mac OS X you can `Right Click` and go to `Get Info` and then select a different app for `Open with:` option:

[image]

For Windows 10, see help document: https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-set-default-programs-and-file-types-in-windows-10/

Comment: i have tried this by right clicking and properties, but then this defaults all of my html pages to open with sublime, i have webpages saved to my desktop, that now default to sublime also...??

Answer (score 0):

If you are a windows user or linux user , You can easily achieve it by following steps:

**Windows**:

- Right Click to file and select properties
- Go to open with option and click on change
- pop will show different application which supports the file if you are not able to see sublime click on browse
- Browse it to sublime in program files
- choose sublime
- done your file will not look as the web page instead of that it will appear as sublime text file

**Linux**:

- You will get sublime in the browse option if it installed into your system

Comment: Using Mac OS or windows ?

Comment: using windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

You could save it as HTML, (to default open in the browser) and when you need to open it on Sublime simply drag to the editor. (It's similar to right-click Open with, but I think it's quicker).